# Upload image debug trace for tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-s3

I am using S3 for uploading images from my java web based application. When I am uploading in console I see all binary code of uploaded file, like this:

`[2012-12-30 17:09:13,347] [http-bio-8081-exec-5] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - >> "[0xd7][0xfe][0x16][0xaa]g[0xda]y.[0x8e][0xa6]~[0xb0][0xa7]\[0xc4]k[0xa0][0x12][0x8e][0xcb][0xad][0x8b]X6_v[0xb9][0xdb]][0x1][0xb1]`[0x94][0xb9][0x89]*[0xdb]j[0x4][0x9]-[0xad][0xab]r[0xe][0xdb]gV4[0x85]V5I[0x89];[0xaa][0xb4]DZ[0xd0]8B,[0xb6]P[0xf6][0xb3][0x9d][0xea][0x89][0x80][0xcb][0xe5] 
[2012-12-30 17:09:13,347] [http-bio-8081-exec-5] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - >> "1[0xd2]W[\n]"`

A lot of lines. How I can remove it from debugger?

Eclipse, Tomcat 7.0, Log4J

**Solution**
`log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire=WARN`
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html

Comment: We need more info here, logging framework, web container?

Comment: I'm working with J2EE Eclipse, Tomcat 7.0

Comment: Then I'd read up on tomcat logging (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html). I think they provide examples of how to configure log levels.

Comment: it's DEBUG level, I can't remove it at all.

Comment: So what? Out of the box tomcat uses JDK logging if I remember correctly, that can be disabled from your Console by changing the appropriate configuration file (read the linked page?)

Comment: We are using log4j logger

Comment: So change the log4j.properties file?